# Average of the longest path of a BST

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the sum and average of data of type `int` from a longest path of a BST. I've made the following functions :

```
int table::longest(){
   return longest(root);
}

int table::longest(node* curr){
   int suml = 0;
   int sumr = 0;

    if(!curr)
        return 0;
    int hleft = height(curr->left);
    int hright = height(curr->right);
    if(hleft > hright){
        suml = curr->data;
        return  suml += longest(curr->left);
    }
    sumr = curr->data;
    return sumr += longest(curr->right);
}

int table::height(node* curr){
    if(!curr)
        return 0;
    int hLeft = 1 +  height(curr->left);
    int hRight = 1 + height(curr->right);

    if(hLeft > hRight)
        return hLeft;
    return hRight;
}
```

The function `longest` returns me the sum of the data, but how to return its average without traversing the tree again in order to figure out how many nodes are in the longest path?

EDIT: The prototype of private function `longest` has to be `int longest(node* root)` and it has to return the average or at least the sum of the elements to the public function so it can return the average knowing the sum

Comment: You already traverse twice (actually, `N` times where `N` is the depth of the tree - your algorithm is quadratic in depth). `height` does its own traversal. You need a single function that returns both the height and the sum of weights together - that'll minimize the work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: how can I do that having the given function prototype ?

Comment: Write a helper function having a different prototype, call it from this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not optimized. Unnecessary repeating the traversal is never recommended. You can use the given below function. It will do the task in O(n) time, where n is the number of nodes in binary tree.

```
int maxHeight = 0;
int longestPathSum = 0;

int table::longest(){
   longest(root, 0, 0);
   return longestPathSum;
}

void table::longest(node* curr, int sum, int height){
    if(curr == NULL) return 0;
    sum += curr->data;
    if(++height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = height;
        longestPathSum =  sum;
    }       
    longest(curr->left, sum, height);
    longest(curr->right, sum, height);
}
```

> find the sum and average of data of type int from a longest path of a BST

sum = longestPathSum;

average = longestPathSum / maxHeight;

Comment: The problem is that my function `longest` has to be of the form `int longest(node* root)`. I can't change it and it has to return the average. Or at least return the sum and the public function `longest` to return the average knowing the sum

Answer (score 0):

Instead of function 'longest' returning the sum of weights, you can pass the sum of weights and height as reference. This will allow not traversing the BST twice.

Comment: The function longest has to be like that. That is a requirement of the problem